# Umbraco 7 - Update dictionary item's value via code

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco7

There's Umbraco's Dictionary section which contains all its items.
I'm trying to find a way to update the value of a specific item via my code (.NET).
I know how can I get the value, but don't know how to set and update it.
Any recommendations?

Comment: if my answer has helped you to fix your problem, please remember to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Umbraco's LocalizationService](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/management/services/localizationservice/) to create your dictionary items and get them programmatically, then this is how you update an existing dictionary item's value;

```
// Get the existing dictionary item to delete it
var dictionaryItem = _localizationService.GetDictionaryItemByKey(data.Key);
    
// Get all languages
var allActiveLanguages=_localizationService.GetAllLanguages();
                        
// Set your language - I only have one language, which is why I'm getting the first one here
var language = allActiveLanguages.FirstOrDefault();
    
                        
if (language != null)
{
 _localizationService.AddOrUpdateDictionaryValue(dictionaryItem, language, "New dictionary value is here!!");
}

// Save your updates    
_localizationService.Save(dictionaryItem);
```

PS: Below image is how you can use the ILocationService.

PSS: For more code examples, please take a [look at here.](https://gist.github.com/jamiepollock/5440e7d3c12fceaa4134)

[image]

[image]